# How to track change of JSON data over time for large number of entities?

Tags: statistics, bigdata, analytics, audit

I have a system that checks the status of a large number of entities on schedule every minute. For each entity, there would be a JSON file which has fields indicating the statuses for different attributes. The system dumps these JSON files on a network share.

Each run of the schedule that runs every minute generates a JSON with 20k odd entities like these having tens of attributes.

```
[
    {
        "entityid": 12345,
        "attribute1": "queued",
        "attribute2": "pending"
    },
    {
        "entityid": 34563,
        "attribute1": "running",
        "attribute2": "successful"
    }
]
```

I need to be able to track the change of attribute status of the entities over time, for instance, answer questions like when did the status of `entity x` become "pending". What is the best way to store this data and generate the stats?

Comment: have you tried to use the diff lib?
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should store your data in a database. If your data have always the same structure, you could use a "classical" database like Postgresql or Mysql. If your data is of irregular shape, look at NoSQL databases like MongoDB. If you need to get your data in JSON you can easily export data from database to JSON.

Here is an article which discuss about JSON and database : https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

In case you only change the value of some fields in your dict, and don't want to use a DB, the best bet would be to:
1) Convert your Json file to a string, for this you can use `json.dumps`, 
2) Use the diff lib for comparing both strings (before and after the update):
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html